# Write directly to a network printer

Tags: c++, windows, printing

This code got from [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162959(v=vs.85).aspx) to write directly to a printer does not seem to work with a network printer.

I get "printer name is invalid" in OpenPrinter function when I give my network printer's name.

How to write directly to a network printer

Comment: What string format are you passing?

Comment: I dont think that's the problem. I am passing Unicode..

Comment: First sentence of the article: "The code sample later in this topic shows how to send printer control data directly to printers that use **GDI-based** printer drivers." But for a network printer, the obvious way would be " open a TCP connection, send data". Naturally the challenge is then _what_ data to send, but presumably you already know that given that you want direct access.

Comment: @MSalters https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/138594/howto-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-the-win32-api . The second sentence of the article says that it'll work for networked printers.

Comment: "in Windows NT or Windows 95.". Your second link is clearly an earlier version of the same article. So, Microsoft found it necessary to remove the statement that it works for networked printers, and they added wording that it applies to GDI printers. Feel free to dig up your Windows 95 floppies, but I bet you were testing on a 21st century version of Windows.